# accessing a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this nested dictionary that I want to access:

```
menu = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}
```

I want to access the first "cost" (espresso) in this nested dictionary, I tried doing menu["cost"], but it won't work, can anyone help?

Comment: `menu['espresso']['cost']`…!?

Comment: Which cost do you want?  `menu['espresso']['cost']` would get you the 1.5 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the cost of a specific item,

```py
cost = menu["espresso"]["cost"]
# 1.5
```

For future reference,

If you wanted a list of all the prices,

```py
costs = [item["cost"] for item in menu.values()]
# [1.5, 2.5, 3.0]
```

If you wanted a list of tuples of `item_name, cost`,

```py
costs = [(key, value["cost"]) for key, value in menu.items()]
# [('espresso', 1.5), ('latte', 2.5), ('cappuccino', 3.0)]
```

If you wanted a dictionary of `item_name: cost`,

```py
costs = {key : value["cost"] for key, value in menu.items()}
# {'espresso': 1.5, 'latte': 2.5, 'cappuccino': 3.0}
```